# How to break permutation group in normal subgroup and the quotient group?

Tags: permutations, maple

could you give steps to show this decomposition

or show in maple code

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_group

Comment: **Which** permutation group?

Comment: Where are these questions coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a finite group. The set of all non-identity normal subgroups of $G$ is a non-empty finite set (it's finite because $G$ is finite and it's nonempty because $G$ is a normal subgroup of itself). Therefore, there exists a minimal normal subgroup $N_1$ of $G$. $N_1$ need not be unique! (See the exercises below.)

The quotient $G/N_1$ (which exists because $N_1$ is normal in $G$) in turn possesses a minimal normal subgroup. Under the canonical bijection between subgroups of $G/N_1$ and subgroups of $G$ containing $N_1$, this minimal normal subgroup of $G/N_1$ corresponds to a normal subgroup of $G$ containing $N_1$. Let's denote it by $N_2$. $N_2$ is minimal with respect to the property that it is a normal subgroup of $G$ properly containing $N_1$. $N_2$ need not be unique! (... for the same reason that $N_1$ need not be unique!)

The process continues inductively and it must terminate because $G$ is finite; the last term of the process will, of course, be $G$. So, we end up with a sequence

$\{e\}=N_0\triangleleft N_1\triangleleft\cdots\triangleleft N_{k-1}\triangleleft N_k=G$

where the notation $\triangleleft$ signifies "is a normal subgroup of" and $e$ denotes the identity element of $G$. Such a series is known as a **composition series** of the group $G$. Note that each quotient group in this series $N_{i+1}/N_i$ for all $0\leq i\leq k-1$ is a simple group. The quotients are sometimes known as the **composition factors** of the composition series. The **composition length** of $G$ is the number of non-identity terms in a composition series of $G$ (so it's $k$, not $k+1$, in the notation of the process described above). It turns out that the composition length doesn't depend on which composition series of $G$ you choose. So we can speak of *the* composition length!

***Exercise 1***: Verify that $\{e\}\triangleleft \{(1 2),(1 3),(2 3)\}\triangleleft S_3$ and $\{e\}\triangleleft \{(1 2 3),(1 3 2)\}\triangleleft S_3$ are composition series for $S_3$.

***Exercise 2***: What is the composition length of the following groups:

**(a)** An abelian group?

**(b)** The permutation group $S_3$?

**(c)** (challenge) The permutation group $S_4$?

**(d)** (challenge) The alternating group $A_4$? (If you couldn't figure out (c), then what is the composition of length in terms of the (possibly unknown) composition length of $S_4$?)

***Exercise 3***: What are the composition factors of the groups you considered in ***Exercise 2***?

***Exercise 4 (Jordan-Holder)***: Prove that the composition length and the isomorphism classes of the composition factors of a finite group are independent of the chosen composition series. (This exercise is difficult and it's known as the Jordan-Holder theorem; try induction on the order of the group to get started.)

***Exercise 5***: Prove that there is a unique composition series of $S_n$ for all $n\geq 5$ and find it! (*Hint*: first prove that the only non-trivial proper normal subgroup of $S_n$ for $n\geq 5$ is $A_n$, the alternating group on $n$ letters.)

I hope this helps!

Comment: maple command do not have quotient, how do you do the quotient? http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=permgroup

Comment: @bolo Sorry, I'm not sure as I'm not familiar with Maple. Hopefully , someone who is familiar with Maple can elaborate on that point. In any case, you don't even need to use quotient groups in my procedure above. One alternative is to just take $N_2$ to be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ properly containing $N_1$ (and then continue the process inductively). Certainly, this is equivalent to the procedure I described above and works just as well. And, of course, to say $N_2$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ properly containing $N_1$ is to say it's a minimal element of the ...

Comment: @bolo ... partially ordered set consisting of all normal subgroups of $G$ properly containing $N_1$ (this set is partially ordered by inclusion). Do you think this version of the construction can be done via Maple? (I will not be around on Stack Exchange for the next few hours so if you leave any further comments, then I will respond in a few hours of time.)

Comment: i understand your working, it is G/(G/((G/N1))) if you can further provide the steps to calculate quotient just as like working in paper with your pen. I will click your answer correct. Just examples of permutation for quotient is enough